# Imported aerial imagery coming into qgis crooked

Tags: qgis

I'm new to qgis and am learning how to download basemaps from various sources. I've been working on a fairly simple map using aerial imagery downloaded from the USGS National Map. Whenever I import the map into my qgis project, the map comes in crooked. Instead of normal north/south orientation, the maps are rotated (approximately 45 degrees) counterclockwise. Is this a projection problem, or am I doing something else wrong. Also, is there a way to correct that within qgis (rotate axis to true north/south).

Answer (score 0):

In similar situations I've found that the *projection* of the layers didn't match. Something to check